# React hook state variable sharing between React Navigation stack screens?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

EDIT:
For those stumbling on this, disregard this question. It was a simple mistake on my end. React hook variable sharing between screen components works fine.

I have my `App.js` file as follows

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Main from './src/Main';
import Game from './src/Game';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Game" component={Game} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

`Main.js` (relevant parts)

```js
export default function Main({ navigation }) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState(null);
  ...
  <TextInput
    mode='outlined'
    label='Enter username here'
    onChangeText={text => setUsername(text)}
  />
  <Button
    mode='contained'
    onPress={() => 
      navigation.navigate('Game', {'username': username})
    }
  >
    Create
  </Button>
  ...
```

`Game.js` (relevant parts)

```js
export default function Game({ navigation, route }) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        {route.params.username}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

How do I pass in my `username` state variable using React hooks from my `Main` component to my `Game` component? Currently I'm getting the following error on the `{route.params.username}` line in `Game.js`:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {replace, push, pop, popToTop, goBack, navigate, reset, setParams, dispatch, isFocused, canGoBack, dangerouslyGetParent, dangerouslyGetState, addListener, removeListener, setOptions}).

I just want to pass in whatever the most recent string value of `username` is after the button in `Main` screen is clicked (which should navigate away to `Game` screen), but it seems like the passed in value is an object.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code, can you add a console.log(route.params) and add the result to your question?

Comment: @SagharMirali it just prints out an object with keys {replace, push, pop, popToTop, goBack, navigate, reset, setParams, dispatch, isFocused, canGoBack, dangerouslyGetParent, dangerouslyGetState, addListener, removeListener, setOptions}
I just want the string value of `username`

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, maybe create a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/) that shows of the problem?

Comment: @BasvanderLinden https://snack.expo.io/yMVU0A4cU

Comment: Full error is here: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=31&args[]=Error%3A%20Minified%20React%20error%20%23310%3B%20visit%20https%3A%2F%2Freactjs.org%2Fdocs%2Ferror-decoder.html%3Finvariant%3D310%20for%20the%20full%20message%20or%20use%20the%20non-minified%20dev%20environment%20for%20full%20errors%20and%20additional%20helpful%20warnings.&args[]=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted in the question works fine, but I think I found the problem(s) from looking at your snack.

The first thing is that your `utils.createGame` function expects one parameter `username`, but you pass `navigation` to it and `username` like this:

```
onPress={() =>
  utils.createGame(navigation, username).then(payload => {
    navigation.navigate("Game", payload);
  })
}
```

So remove `navigation` as a parameter instead:

```
onPress={() =>
  utils.createGame(username).then(payload => {
    navigation.navigate("Game", payload);
  })
}
```

The same thing goes for `utils.addPlayer` where the function takes two parameters, but you pass three.

---

To give more context, but to also fix another problem, change how you define `utils` to this:

```
const utils = {
  createGame: async function(username) {
    const gameId = cryptorandomstring({ length: 6, type: 'distinguishable' });
    const playerId = cryptorandomstring({ length: 10 });

    return { 'gameId': gameId, 'creatorId': playerId, 'username': username };
  },

  addPlayer: async function(username, gameId) {
    const playerId = cryptorandomstring({ length: 10 });

    return { 'gameId': gameId, 'playerId': playerId, 'username': username };
  }
}
```

Inside `addPlayer` you had a return statement like this:

```
return { 'gameId': gameId, 'playerId': playerId, 'playerUserName': username };
```

The problem with this as that inside `Game.js` you're destructuring `username` from the params and not `playerUserName`. So the destructured `username` variable won't hold the correct value.